# MongoDB Aggregation Query - Group aggregate field error

Tags: mongodb, aggregate

I have a MongoDB collection, with one document such as -

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a187babdbf0a03cdca0d0bc"),
    "aggregationDate" : "2017-10-31",
    "ipaddress" : "10.65.66.184",
    "first" : {
        "count" : 3
    },
    "second" : {
        "count" : 2
    },
    "third" : {
        "count" : 3
    },
}
```

There are around 30000 such documents, with around 1000 new ones generated every day. I want to display the "ipaddress" having highest activity, which is defined as highest count of "first", "second" and "third".

I looked up aggregation queries and wrote the following one -

```
db.collection.aggregate({ $group : { ipaddress: "$ipaddress", 
                          max: { $max : [ "$first.count", "$second.count", "$third.count" }}});
```

I unfortunately get an error -

```
"errmsg" : "exception: the group aggregate field 'ipaddress' must be defined as an expression inside an object",
```

Can someone please help me with this error and also with writing an aggregation query for my requirement? Thanks

Comment: Are you looking for highest first and second and third OR the highest sum of first, second, and third?  E.g. a doc with {first: 10, second: 10, third: 10} might have all the individual highest, but {first: 200, second: 0, third: 0} has a higher sum across the fields.

Comment: @BuzzMoschetti Highest sum of first, second and third is what i am looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick.   You need the `$add` function in there too.

```
db.foo.aggregate([
  {$group: {_id: "$ipaddress",
            max: { $max: {$add: [ "$first.count", "$second.count", "$third.count"] } }
           }
  }
]);
```

Comment: Ah, yes! Thank you so much.. :)

Answer (score 1):

Yeah that's because in the `$group` pipeline you can't have things like that

```
ipaddress: "$ipaddress"
```

The field ipaddress has to be accompanied by an accumulator operator. The documentation here is excellent have a look [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/)

If you mean to group by ipaddress then you have to write it like that:

```
_id: "$ipaddress"
```

Your `$max` operator wont work this way either. This is the way you use it in the `$project` pipeline not in the `$group`. Please take a look [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/max/#grp._S_max)

So your aggregation would have to look like this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
{
    $group: 
    {
        _id: "$ipaddress",
        max: {
            $max: {first: "$first.count", second: "$second.count", third: "$third.count"}
        }
    }
}
])
```